# How can I add single quote character in format function of date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I want to insert a single quote character before year.
`format(parseISO(date), "dd MMM '\''yy");` this does not seem to work. According to date-fns documentation, to add characters, we need to include them between two single quotes. I get the output for the above code as `06 Apr 'yy` whereas the expected output is `06 Apr '20`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format):

> Two single quotes in a row, whether inside or outside a quoted sequence, represent a 'real' single quote. (see the last example)

The last example shows how to do it:

```
// Escape string by single quote characters:
var result = format(new Date(2014, 6, 2, 15), "h 'o''clock'")
//=> "3 o'clock"
```

So in your case it should be:

```
format(parseISO(date), "dd MMM ''yy");
```